# python pandas convert a dictionary to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

i have two dictionaries as follows. I can convert the first to a dataframe , but the second gives error. Why?

```
d = {'id': ['CS2_056'], 'cost': [2], 'name': ['Tap']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

raw_data1 = {
        'subject_id': 3,
        'first_name': 4, 
        'last_name': 7}
raw_data1
dfz = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1 )
```

Comment: What's the error message? Also, why do you have `raw_data1` on it's own line, not part of a `print` or anything?

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you are not passing an index, which is required when using scalar values. So to solve your issue you would do:

`pd.DataFrame(raw_data1, index=[0])`

Comment: so `[]` make all the difference? would you be able to explain what does index really mean? i looked into help `index : Index or array-like
Index to use for resulting frame. Will default to np.arange(n) if no indexing information part of input data and no index provided` but didnt understand a lot. In case of 1st example why doesnt it throw the error?